# Android Get Distinct contacts on the basis of phone number and display name

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor

I am trying to get distinct contacts on the base of phone number and name. I got all the contacts but getting repetitions. Here is my code

```
  Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
    };


Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                uri, projection,ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "!=''", null, null);// uri, projection,selection+ ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "!=''", null, null);`
if (phones.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                long ID = phones.getLong(phones.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));
                String DisplayName = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(projection[1]));
                String Key = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(projection[2]));

                if (Key != null && Key.toString().trim().length() > 0 && (Key.startsWith("0") || Key.startsWith("+"))) {
                    ContactBean contactModel = new ContactBean(DisplayName, Key, "");



                    list.add(contactModel);
                } else {
                    // No number!!
                }
            } while (phones.moveToNext());
        }
```

Any help to get distinct contacts.

My projection is already applying the Distinction on it. When I try to apply distinct query on it like this

```
  String selection = " 'SELECT DISTINCT " + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME+"'";
```

I got this error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id, display_name, data1 FROM view_data_restricted data LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT data_usage_stat.data_id as STAT_DATA_ID, SUM(data_usage_stat.times_used) as times_used, MAX(data_usage_stat.last_time_used) as last_time_used FROM data_usage_stat GROUP BY data_usage_stat.data_id) as data_usage_stat ON (STAT_DATA_ID=data._id) WHERE (1) AND (( 'SELECT DISTINCT contact_id'mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2' AND data1!=''))
```

Which indicates that my projection is already applying a selection. But why it is not working.Any solutions?

Comment: Already tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507665/how-to-select-unique-contacts-from-android

Comment: Did this ever work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
// set as global
Set<string> phonenumbersList = new HashSet<string>();

            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            //contact has name number and phonenumber does not exists in list
            if ( phoneNumber != null && name != null && !phonenumbersList.contains(phoneNumber)){ 
                planets = new ContactsList[]{ new ContactsList(name, phoneNumber) };

                phonenumbersList.add(phoneNumber);
                planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));
                planetList.Add(phoneNumber, name);
            }
            }
            phones.close();
```

easy way to get phonenumbers and contact names