# How to access Unique contacts in android app?

Tags: android, android-contacts

Here is the Code to access contacts in android:

```
    private void getContact() {
        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        arrayListname=new ArrayList<>();
        arrayListmobno=new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("hello");
//        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"+ ("1") + "'";
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, selection
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                + "=1", null, sortOrder);





            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {

                final String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                final String mob=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                final String regexStr = "^(?:(?:\\+|0{0,2})91(\\s*[\\-]\\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\\d{9}$";
                System.out.println("omgname "+name +" mob "+mob);
            }
    }
```

Here All the contacts in the contact list are accessed

Output:

[image: Output:]

Url:

[image: Url]

Comment: Don't post text as image

Comment: I am really sorry Sir, It's the output of logcat file

Comment: what u exactly want to do? and what do u mean by unique contacts?

Comment: I mean some contacts in the contact list are Comman/similar to each other.I want to fetch only those which are unique @MajidAli

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13509116/7924565.. try  the query in this answer

Comment: Sir, I have already read that post. there `final String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                final String mob=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));` doesnt work @MajidAli

Comment: if you only want to prevent duplication then sort them with hashset..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214068/discussion-between-pauls-omg-hardware-and-majid-ali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may append the contacts to string and send 50 contacts at once to php page.

java code:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                final String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                final String mob = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));


                final String regexStr = "^(?:(?:\\+|0{0,2})91(\\s*[\\-]\\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\\d{9}$";
                System.out.println("omgname " + name + " mob " + mob);

                arrayListname.add(name.trim());
                arrayListmobno.add(mob.trim());

                if (mob.length() > 9 && !mob.contains("-") && !name.equals("") && !name.equals(".")) {
                    final String myname = name.replaceAll(" ", "_").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", "");
                    final String mymobno = mob.replaceAll(" ", "");

                         arrayListmobno.add(mymobno);

                    count = count + 1;

                    if (count == 50) {
                        System.out.println(namearray + "namearrayomg");
                        System.out.println(mobnoarray + "mobnoarrayomg");

                        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url);
                        String contacts_url = url + "request=contactsarrayList&arrayListname=" + namearray + "&arrayListmobno=" + mobnoarray + "&userid=" + id;
                        System.out.println(contacts_url);
                        AndroidNetworking.get(contacts_url)
                                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                                .build()
                                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                                        try {

                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JSON Error" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                                        anError.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                });


                        namearray = "";
                        mobnoarray = "";
                        count = 0;


                    } else {
                        namearray = namearray + myname + ",";
                        mobnoarray = mobnoarray + mymobno.trim() + ",";

                    }

                }
```

php code:

```
public function contactsarrayList($arrayListname=0,$arrayListmobno=0,$userid=0)
    {
        global $con;
        $arrayListname = substr($arrayListname, 0, -1);
        $arrayListmobno = substr($arrayListmobno, 0, -1);

        $narray =  explode(',', $arrayListname);
        $marray = explode(',', $arrayListmobno);
        $len=count($narray);
        for ($i=0; $i < $len ; $i++) { 

            $retrived1 = $con->query("insert into contacts(userid,name,mobno) values({$userid},'{$narray[$i]}','{$marray[$i]}')");
        }
    }
```

I know this looks bit complicated but will work

also add composite unique key to the contacts table in database so that no contact will be repeated

Comment: I appreciate your work sir,but it does solve the problem but `namearray = namearray + myname + ",";mobnoarray = mobnoarray + mymobno.trim() + ",";` these two arrays still contains duplicate records

Comment: The duplicate contacts will not be inserted in the table because of composite unique key @Paul'somgHardware

Comment: But unnecessary duplication in url still presist

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to add the details (phone number) and (name) in a list and prevent duplicates.

If that is the case:

Then add the details to the lists if they already don't exist:

```
private void getContact() {
arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
arrayListname=new ArrayList<>();
arrayListmobno=new ArrayList<>();

String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"+ ("1") + "'";
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, selection
                + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                + "=1", null, sortOrder);


while (cursor.moveToNext()){

final String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
final String mob=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
final String regexStr = "^(?:(?:\\+|0{0,2})91(\\s*[\\-]\\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\\d{9}$";

//add details to the list if they don't exist already in the list:

if(!arrayListname.contains(name)){
arrayListname.add(name);
}

if(!arrayListmobno.contains(mob)){
arrayListmobno.add(mob);
}


}

}
```

Comment: This method is used to prevent duplicates in the arraylist. But Suppose There are two contacts with same name but different mobile number,It will create problem in this case.@Hasan Bou Taam